# Аудио передается в AudioSorce, но не проигрывается

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class Audio
{
    public AudioClip GetAudio(string path, string name)
    {
        string audioName = name;
        string soundPath = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/Songs/" + path + audioName;

        WWW request = new WWW(soundPath);

        return request.GetAudioClip();
    }
}
```

Затем я вызываю метод этого класса в Старте другого скрипта

```
private void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = new Audio().GetAudio("Night Drive/", bitmap.AudioFilename);
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip.name = bitmap.AudioFilename;
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip);
    }
```

Таким образом я пытаюсь передать Аудио, оно передается, но не проигрывается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как это аудио выглядит в поле AudioClip в инспекторе. При этом если нажать на этот предпросмотр, оно начнет воспроизведение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибок никаких не возникает

Comment: А вы содержимое строкт `soundPath` в отладчике смотрели? Что там?

Comment: @aepot Там то что и должно быть. Но я на всякий случай проверю ещё раз

Comment: @aepot, к сожалению ошибка не в этом, путь правильный file://C:/Users/User/Documents/Unity Project/Circles/Assets/Songs/Night Drive/audio.mp3 Если ввести это в браузер, откроется тот файл

Comment: Не знаю ответа, но для построения путей лучше используйте класс [Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netcore-3.1#methods). А еще есть не менее полезный класс `Uri`.

Comment: Я думал использовать UnityWebRequest вместо WWW, но у меня он все время выдает ошибку о том что запрос не завершен.

Comment: Для доступа к диск в дотнете полно средств, тот же класс File. Как минимум вы бы смогли его прочитать в массив байт. `byte[] audio = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\...");` или открыть `FileStream`, но как это лучше в Unity сделать - я не знаю. Кстати ваш цикл `while` в решении дает хоть и не надолго, но 100% нагрузку на процессор. Возможно для более корректного решения лучше использовать корутину.

Comment: @aepot спасибо, я попробую вариант с корутиной.

Comment: @aepot, с корутиной не получилось, не знаю почему, но я вставил в цикл эту строку : new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне удалось решить проблему добавлением проверки request.isDone, и только после этого возвращать AudioClip.
Вот код:

```
public AudioClip GetAudio(string path, string name)
    {
        string audioName = name;
        string soundPath = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/Songs/" + path + audioName;

        WWW request = new WWW(soundPath);

        while (!request.isDone)  //жду пока request.isDone станет true
        {
            new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            continue;
        }

        return request.GetAudioClip();
    }
```